# Confusion about links, self, and end2 syntax

Tags: netlogo

```
to surfer-visits-source
  ; The surfer needs to sample the quality of the Target connected to by its anchor Source. If this is less than the expected quality, then surfer will change anchor Source.
  ask surfers [
    let self_surfer (self)
    if ([quality] of one-of [out-link-st-neighbors] of one-of out-link-ss-neighbors) < expected-quality
    [ 
      let temp-end2 ([who] of out-link-ss-neighbors); temp-end2 holds the temporary Source ID
      print(temp-end2)
      create-link-ss-to one-of sources with [who != temp-end2]; create link to some other Source
      ask links-ss with [end1 = self_surfer][
        print("entering KEY block")
        print(self_surfer)
        if end2 = temp-end2 [
         print("entering IF2 block")
         die ; delete old link from Surfer to Source
          print("***********DEAD**************")
       ]
      ]
    ]
  ]

  ; The count of visitors to the anchor Source and the Target has to be incremented

end
```

What I'm trying to do is the following:

Ask all surfers: Are you connected to someone who is connected to someone whose quality variable is set to lower than expected-quality? If so, create a link to someone else (from amongst agenst called sources) whom you are not connected to and delete the old link to the source (who is connected to someone who is of low quality).

I've used a bunch of print statements to help debug, and I noticed that it enters the KEY block, but does not enter IF2 block. So, in the end, it does not kill links to the sources that are connected to the low quality targets. I get no statement saying "DEAD" even though the initial conditions should ensure that at least a few links are killed off, if not all.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the `end2` doesn't report the [who] of the linked turtle, but the turtle itself. So you can check

```
let temp-end2 ([who] of one-of out-link-ss-neighbors)
if [who] of end2 = temp-end2
```

Comment: I used the one-of statement because I've set it up such that there is only one ss neighbour and one st neighbour. So each one-of would return the only one that there is.

Comment: To give you an idea of the structure, each surfer is linked to one ss neighbour who is linked to one st neighbour.

Comment: The ss neighbour is called source and the st neighbour of the source is called the target. So, surfer-> source-> target.

Comment: It is still not entering the IF2 block, when I tried your second piece of code (the first piece of code doesn't work for me). I used some print statements to see what's happening...for "print(temp-end2)", it prints [number], while for "[who] of end2", it prints number (without square brackets). Could this be the cause, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense and probably is the problem. When you `let temp-end2 ([who] of out-link-ss-neighbors)` you create a list containing the who numbers of all neighbors, even if it is just one. You can again use the trick with `one-of` to just save the number:
`let temp-end2 ([who] of one-of out-link-ss-neighbors)` should do it

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. It's working now, thanks.

Comment: Instead of comparing who numbers, you can just compare agents directly. It's rarely necessary or appropriate in NetLogo to use who numbers at all. Instead, refer to agents and agentsets directly.